# What is wrong with those two DML statements?

Tags: sql

2 DML statements in question:

1.

```
DELETE FROM destination WHERE DCountry='USA'
Customer(FName, LName, HCountry)
```

2.

```
UPDATE customer SET HCountry='CH' and LName = 'Carlson'
WHERE FName='Joe'
```

**Data Base:**

Destination(DID, DName, DCountry)
Booking(DID, LName, Year, Price)
– Attribute DID is a foreign key to Destination.DID
– Attribute LName is a foreign key to Customer.LName

I think for the UPDATE statement the mistake could lie in having tow SET statements. Is that correct?
For the fist one I am really clueless.

example instance of the database

[image: example]

Comment: Did you write those, or is this a school assignment to spot errors?

Comment: Is from an exercise.

Comment: Try your SQL statements here: https://dbfiddle.uk/, and do a fast syntax check here https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question I assume you are facing issues with both the queries and have not implemented DELETE/UPDATE cascade for foreign keys.

You should not delete the contents of one table when a column is being referenced as foreign key in another table. You may want to implement **DELETE CASCADE and UPDATE CASCADE** options for foreign keys of your table. These constraints take care of the referenced table if the data is removed/deleted from the parent table. You can refer to [this link](https://www.sqlshack.com/delete-cascade-and-update-cascade-in-sql-server-foreign-key/) for help with the implementation. You can also find ways to alter existing foreign keys and set CASCADE constraints for them.

Also the Update query you have specified is a bit incorrect. When you try to update multiple columns using UPDATE query you need not use word 'AND' in between the columns. Separating it with a comma (,) is the syntax as below:

```
UPDATE customer SET HCountry='CH',LName = 'Carlson' WHERE FName='Joe'
```

Answer (score 0):

tokuro your first Query Was Right

but in Second query use , instead of and keyword to Update Multiple Column like this

```
UPDATE customer SET HCountry='CH',LName = 'Carlson' WHERE FName='Joe'
```